# Using CodedUI to automate a windows calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

This is the code that i am using. but unfortunately it is not running as expected. can someone help me out with this?

This is coded ui test. i want to automate the calculator on windows 10 and this is not allowing me to do so. im using visual studio 2015 and my windows is 10. i am creating a new project of coded ui by going to new>new project>test>coded ui test template.

```
public class CodedUITest1
{
    public CodedUITest1()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        string ApplicationPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
        //ApplicationUnderTest application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(ApplicationPath);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ApplicationPath);

        WinWindow maW = new WinWindow();
        maW.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Calculator");
        maW.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");

        WinButton btnSeven = new WinButton(maW);
        btnSeven.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "7");
        btnSeven.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
        Mouse.Click(btnSeven);

        WinButton btnPlus = new WinButton(maW);
        btnPlus.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Add");
        btnPlus.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
        Mouse.Click(btnPlus);

        WinButton btnThree = new WinButton(maW);
        btnThree.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "3");
        btnThree.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
        Mouse.Click(btnThree);

        WinButton btnEquals = new WinButton(maW);
        btnEquals.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Equals");
        btnEquals.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
        Mouse.Click(btnEquals);

        WinText txtResult = new WinText(maW);
        txtResult.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Result");
        txtResult.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
        Assert.AreEqual("10", txtResult.DisplayText);

        Playback.Wait(1000);
    }


    #region Additional test attributes

    // You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:

    ////Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
    //[TestInitialize()]
    //public void MyTestInitialize()
    //{        
    //    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
    //}

    ////Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
    //[TestCleanup()]
    //public void MyTestCleanup()
    //{        
    //    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
    //}

    #endregion


    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls;

Comment: the upper are the using namespaces used for the project.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You've just said it isn't running as expected.  What is it doing, what do you want it to do, and where do you think the problem may be?

Comment: Please edit your original question and put the using statements in the question, rather than dumping them in the comments section

Comment: @LordWilmore i tried to add all of it in the question it is not allowing me to do so. 
Actually it throws an exception "An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.TechnologyNotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: The exception is thrown at Mouse.Click(btnSeven);

Comment: (1) Please [edit] the question to include the missing code, do not put it in comments. (2) Please create a [mcve], remove the code after the point of failure as that just confuses the question. I.e., make a "minimal" example. (3) Try using Coded UI's record and generate tool and see what code it produces for the same task.

Comment: Maybe the 7 button on your calculator is broken.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit no its not broken.

Comment: @AdrianHHH  i tried to add all of it in the question it is not allowing me to do so.